# Acces Gsuite admindirectory from other domain in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I have created a Web application based on the Google HTML service. I want to consult data from another Gsuite domain via this web application.

Is it possible to access the admindirectory of the other domain via generated credentials?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.